# Implementing horizontal tabs in Jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, tabs

Good afternoon

I have not worked much with Html and Layout , and now i am working with JSP.
I want to build a simple page with four horizontal tabs.
Each time a user click on a tab a complete different page should appear :
My question is :
What is the best way to implement ?
Something like this ?(this could be someting like header template)

```
>  <ul id="tablist">
>         <li><a class="current" href="/action1">Tab0</a></li>
>         <li><a href="/action2">Tab1</a></li>
>         <li><a href="/action3">Tab2</a></li>
>         <li><a href="/action4">Tab3</a></li>
>        </ul>
```

Or should i use one specific tag library?
Or something completely different ?

I am new to this , so sorry because i know that this a very newbie question.
Thanks in advance
Best regards developer community

Answer (score 0):

I know absolutely nothing about jsp so this may not be the answer you're looking for but if you want to have a horizontal list it would be easiest to do it with css... So you have the html code then in your css you would have...

```
#tablist {
  list-style: none;              /* Gets rid of bullet points  */
}

#tablist li {
  display: inline;               /* IMPORTANT makes the list horizontal  */
}
```

Those are the two more important ones. With css you can make more aesthetic changes but this will accomplish the horizontal line of links.